# XY datapairs for BEMSimpleLineGraph

Tags: ios, objective-c, bemsimplelinegraph

The datasets in plots I have in my `iOS` app, are XY pairs, both the X and Y coordinate are `CGFloat` values.  However, by looking at the source code of `BEMSimpleLineGraph`, there only seems to be a way to pass in Y values, and not XY pairs.  The objective is, when the user zooms in, I'd like the labels on the X-axis to display more decimals.

For instance:

- 800 - 801 - 802 - 803 - 804 - 805
- 802.5 - 803.0 - 803.5 - 804.0 - 804.5 - 805.0
- 803.02 - 803.03 - 803.04 - 803.05 - 803.06 - 803.7
- etc

Is this possible with `BEMSimpleLineGraph` ?

Answer (score 0):

The zooming functionality you're talking about is currently not supported by [BEMSimpleLineGraph](https://github.com/Boris-Em/BEMSimpleLineGraph).
Otherwise, you could pass the Y data to the data source and the X data as string for the X-axis labels.